# Find characteristic polynomial of $A+I$ if is knowing characteristic polynomial of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_{3 \times 3}$ and let $x^3 - x$ be characteristic polynomial. Determine  characteristic polynomial of $A+I$.

We have eigenvalues of $A$: $0,1,-1$ so $A$ is similar to $\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$. Then we have that characteristic polynomial of $A+I$ is equal: $\mbox{det}(A+I - xI) = \mbox{det}(A+(1-x)I)= \mbox{det} \left(  \begin{bmatrix} 1-x&0&0\\0&2-x&0\\0&0&x\end{bmatrix}\right) =x(1-x)(2-x) $

I don't have answer for this task, because it come from an exam, and I'm not sure does it work (I only suppose). I will grateful for your help.

Answer (score 8):

$$\chi_{A+I}(x)=\det(A+I-xI)=\det(A-(x-1)I)=\chi_A(x-1)$$

Comment: Alternatively, to arrive at the same conclusion, one could notice the factorizations of $\chi_A(X)$ and $\chi_{A+I}(X)$ noting that the eigenvalues of $A+I$ are precisely $x+1$ those of $A$.